# FineTuning of pre-trained Sentence Transformer model on code examples recommendation task

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, sentence-transformers

I am trying to figure out how to complete fine-tuning on a Java code dataset for the Code Examples Recommendation task.
I'm using `all-mpnet-base-v2` pre-trained model of Sentence Transformer.

```
# Function to preprocessing dataset.
def preprocess_data():
    """
    Cleans dataset and create training pairs using query and code examples.
    """
    pairs = []
    # Create pairs (query, code example) from dataset.
    for _, row in tqdm(dataset.iterrows(), desc='Preprocessing'):
        # Remove tag from queries.
        query = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', re.sub(r'[\t\n]', ' ', BeautifulSoup(row['Query'], 'lxml').get_text())).strip()

        for code_example in row['CodeExamples']:
            # Remove tag from code examples.
            code_example = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', re.sub(r'[\t\n]', ' ', code_example)).strip()

            # Add pair (query, code example) to train examples list.
            pairs.append((query, code_example))
        
    # Generate train set of pair (query, code example)
    train_set = [
        InputExample(texts=[pair[0], pair[1]])
        for pair in tqdm(pairs, desc='Create training set')
    ]

    return train_set

# Function to fine-tune model
def fine_tune_model(model, train_set, batch_size: int = 4, epochs: int = 5, output_path: str = './model/'):
    # Create DataLoader from training dataset.
    dataloader = DataLoader(train_set, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)

    # Define loss.
    train_loss = losses.MultipleNegativesRankingLoss(model=model)
        
    # Execute fine-tuning.
    model.fit(
        train_objectives = [(dataloader, train_loss)],
        epochs = epochs,
        output_path = output_path
    )
```

I would not know if the process I followed is correct. My dataset consists only of queries and related code examples provided for that query, without labels (however, I could also follow a procedure based only on the code examples, without considering the queries).

What is the best process I can implement. That is, how can I construct the training set and the validation set? What loss should I consider? What evaluator and what parameters should I use? The model I have used is correct for my task?